# Setting path to shared library inside a makefile for compile

Tags: linux, makefile, linker, libxlsxwriter

I want to compile a program using makefile which is linked against the zlib shared libraries which it is different from the one installed on my system. But I don't want them to be permanently added to the library pool of my system.

The path of custom zlib is /usr/work/libxlsxwriter-master/zlib-1.2.8

I have tried to use something like:

```
ZLIBDIR=/usr/work/libxlsxwriter-master/zlib-1.2.8

# The static library.
$(LIBXLSXWRITER_A) : $(OBJS)
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(ZLIBDIR):$(DEPENDENCIES); \
    $(Q)$(AR) $(ARFLAGS)     $@ $(MINIZIP_DIR)/ioapi.o $(MINIZIP_DIR)/zip.o  $^

 # The dynamic library.
 $(LIBXLSXWRITER_SO) : $(SOBJS)
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(ZLIBDIR):$(DEPENDENCIES); \
    $(Q)$(CC) $(SOFLAGS)  -o $@ $(MINIZIP_DIR)/ioapi.so $(MINIZIP_DIR)/zip.so $^ -lz

# Targets for the object files.
%.o  : %.c $(HDRS)
    $(Q)$(CC)       -I$(INC_DIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

 %.so : %.c $(HDRS)
    $(Q)$(CC) -fPIC -I$(INC_DIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

  %.to : %.c $(HDRS)
    $(Q)$(CC) -g -O0 -DTESTING -I$(INC_DIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

When I try to compile, I have this error : /bin/sh: line 1: @ar: command not found

Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: There is an option to have the linker hardcode the path to a library dependency into a library or executable, `-Wl,-rpath`. That might be just what you're looking for. (Leaves `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` free for what it should -- only -- be used for, which is debugging.)

Comment: That being said, I think your problem (`@ar: command not found`) arises from the somewhat peculiar use of `$(Q)`, which I assume you set to `"@"` to "quieten" your makefile. Note that `make -s` (`--silent`) does the same thing.

Comment: @ DevSolar thanks I have remove $(Q) and works. I also added CFLAGS= -O3 -I/usr/work/libxlsxwriter-master/zlib-1.2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where I'm wrong ?

You are wrong in that you modified your `Makefile` incorrectly.

You have a macro `Q`, which evaluates to `@`, which makes the `make` quiet (not print the command it executes) **if** `@` is the first character of the command line. By prepending `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the command line, you screwed that up:

```
# this is a quiet command:
@ar ...

# this is a not quiet command, which tries to execute @ar, which doesn't exist:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... ; @ar ...
```

The second part of wrong is that setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as you did only affects the *building* of the libraries (i.e. the compiler and the linker). What you want is to affect the *runtime* using these libraries, *not* the compiler and linker used to build them.

As DevSolar correctly stated, you want `-rpath` instead:

```
$(Q)$(CC) $(SOFLAGS) -o $@ $(MINIZIP_DIR)/ioapi.so \
  -Wl,-rpath=$(ZLIBDIR) $(MINIZIP_DIR)/zip.so ...
```

Comment: What he says. I had a splitting headache yesterday and couldn't be bothered to put it into that many words. ;-)